# Calling a method from a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class name OFCls which has a method call getOF()

I want to use that method in another class method.

```
public void Display()
{    
    var oOF = new OFCls();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = OFCls.getOF.Tables(0); 
}
```

I get the error MyProject.OFCls.getOF() is a method which is not valid in the given context.

What should I do to call a class method! Thank you heaps

Comment: Could you please show the definition of OFCls and getOF. Are they public, internal, static etc?

Comment: if he create an instance of the class it's obviously not static. `oOF.getOF().Tables[0];` is the proper line but i must misunderstand something because that's very very basic stuff calling methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `getOF` is a method, call it:

```
OFCls.getOF().Tables(0);
```

Comment: oOF.getOF().Tables(0);

Comment: @Dennis I'm not sure whether it's an instance or static method.

Comment: This error - "is not valid in the given context" - tells, that method exists, it is public, and it is instance.

Comment: it says " Non invokable member 'System.Data.DataSet.Tables cannot be used like a method.

Comment: That is a totally different error, saying that whatever `OFCLs.getOF()` returns, has a **property** named `Tables`, not a method. Try `.Tables[0]`.

Comment: @user2967732: may be, you'll learn C# syntax first? `.Tables[0]`.

Comment: Im a vb.net programmer. I got some stuff to edit with C#. I might be good with my mother tongue language. But i don't know all the syntax  Sorry

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing brackets

```
public void Display()
{    
    var oOF = new OFCls();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = OFCls.getOF().Tables[0]; 
}
```

or if it is not static

```
public void Display()
{    
    var oOF = new OFCls();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = oOF .getOF().Tables[0]; 
}
```